# Is there any way to supress error messages in Xubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: configuration, notification

I sometimes see error messages saying

> System Program Problem Detected

I would like to have this popup window giving me these error messages supressed or removed. Actually, ANY error/or message window after starting up the desktop. Is there any way to do this?

I have notifications turned off.

Comment: Can you find something related running`dmesg`?

Comment: sorry you are right this is a duplicate, i did not really check for apport to be the culprit